# Having more than one Database's in one MongoDB instance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it recommended by MongoDB to have one database per instance.
Is it having Multiple Databases per instance will make MongoDB swapping the database in and out of memory for operations which affects the performance.

What can happen in the below case.
We have 2 Databases created in MongoDB
One to Hold the Data(1TB) and other to hold admin related(Max of 1/2GB).

Comment: I think you'll find out testing, imho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MongoDB instance will already have several databases such as local, admin, and config, aside from any that you create.

MongoDB uses the WiredTiger storage engine, which has a cache using a least recently used eviction algorithm.

Each collection and index is kept in its own file on disk, and individual pages of these files are read into the cache when needed.

Once data in the cache exceeds ~80% of its configured maximum size, background eviction workers begin removing the least recently used pages, writing them to disk if they are dirty.

What data is present in the cache at any given moment depends on what has been read or written recently, and is unrelated to how many databases or collections exist in the instance.